# dynamically delete li item in localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code has one small problem that I can not solve.
After refreshing, the price is correct, but in the list li, the item removed remains. I commented on the lines where I have to remove li from localstorage.
Can anyone tell me how I can do it?

```
$(document).on("click", ".addtobasket", function () {

        $("#kontener_koszyka").fadeIn();

        var nazwa = $(this).closest('.produkt').find('.nazwa').text();
        var cena = $(this).closest('.produkt').find('.cenaprzedmiotu').text();
        var id = $(this).closest('.produkt').attr("id");

        var suma = 0;

        var li = "<li data="+id+" class='produkt_w_koszyku'><b>" + nazwa + "</b> <span class='cena_w_koszyku'>" + cena + " zł</span><span style='float: right; margin-right: 30px;' class='deleteitembasket'><i class=\"fas fa-times\"></i></span></li>";

        $("#koszyk").append(li);

        localStorage.setItem('itemlist', (localStorage.getItem('itemlist') || '') + li);

        $("#koszyk .cena_w_koszyku").each(function () {
            suma += parseFloat($(this).text());
        });

        $("#cena span").text(suma.toFixed(2));
        localStorage.setItem('sumalist', suma.toFixed(2));
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.deleteitembasket', function () {
        var nazwa = $(this).closest('.produkt').find('.nazwa').text();
        var cena = $(this).closest('.produkt').find('.cenaprzedmiotu').text();

        var suma = 0;
        var id = $(this).closest('.produkt').attr("id");
        var li = "<li data="+id+" class='produkt_w_koszyku'><b>" + nazwa + "</b> <span class='cena_w_koszyku'>" + cena + " zł</span><span style='float: right; margin-right: 30px;' class='deleteitembasket'><i class=\"fas fa-times\"></i></span></li>";

        $(this).closest("li").remove();
        /* how to remove this li from localStorage? */

        $("#koszyk .cena_w_koszyku").each(function () {
            suma += parseFloat($(this).text());
        });

        $("#cena span").text(suma.toFixed(2));
        localStorage.setItem('sumalist', suma.toFixed(2));
    });

    if (localStorage.getItem('sumalist') != null) {

        $("#koszyk").append(localStorage.getItem('itemlist'));
        $("#cena span").text(localStorage.getItem('sumalist'));
    }
```

Comment: what about `storage.removeItem(keyName);`?

Comment: This delete all li list. I need delete only this item li.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting li you need to reset your localStorage itemlist with currently avaiable list items in DOM.

```
// store a reference to parent tag of all li.
   var $ul = $(this).parents('ul');
    $(this).closest("li").remove();
    // after removing this li Item reset your local Storage as

    localStorage.setItem('itemlist',$ul.html());
```

Comment: updated code. i missed a point and tried accessing li after removing it.

Answer (score 2):

Actually you need to use the `window.localStorage.removeItem()` method:

```
$(this).closest("li").remove();
/* how to remove this li from localStorage? */
```

Just use:

```
window.localStorage.removeItem('itemlist');
```

You can read more about the `localStorage` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).